# mysql select * is not up to date

Tags: php, mysql

i got an issue regarding my sql entities within my table.

i got 2 php-scripts, one adding new items to the table and another fetching all items and return them as a json.

The return script takes some time to return the actual entries. By this i mean if i add or delete an entrie in the table, my return script still shows my entries before deleting/adding them. After some time it gets the right results but i cant explain why.

this is my return code:

```
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"Einkaufsliste");
$sql="SELECT * FROM Einkaufsliste";
$result = $con->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $rows[] = $row;
}

$items = array();
foreach($rows as $row){
    $row_array['item'] = $row['item'];
    array_push($items, $row_array);
}
echo json_encode($items);
/*echo "bla";*/

$con->close();
```

so if i got 3 items in my table and i add one, my return-values are still 3. If i check my db via phpmyadmin there are 4 entries tho.

i forgot to mention this is how i pull my results from via jscript

```
function showItems() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            //document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById("itemList").innerHTML = "";

            var res = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            alert(res);
            for(var k = 0; k < res.length; k++){
                $('#itemList').append('<li><a href="#">'+res[k].item+'</a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li>').listview('refresh');
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getItems.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Your queries are most likely being cached somewhere along the way.

Comment: transactions in the other script? the new rows wouldn't show up in other connections' queries until they're committed.

Comment: phpmyadmin shows them right away if i refresh my entries tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either in the page that outputs the ajax response add no-cache headers:

```
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Or in the ajax call add a parameter with a timestamp so each request will be seen as unique and cached separately, creating the illusion that you turned off caching:

```
var d = new Date();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getItems.php?t="+d.getTime(), true);
```

Or both.

Comment: thank you very much! the date option works fine. duuno if it's intended tho